# logparser TO_TIME output not matching the sql time datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, logparser

Following is the QUERY from logparser :

```
logparser -i:Textline "SELECT TO_DATE(TO_TIMESTAMP(TRIM(EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,'TIMESTAMP')),'M/d/yyyy'))AS DATE, TO_TIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(TRIM(EXTRACT_TOKEN(text,0,'(')),'H:mm:ss')) as TIME from 'C:\xxxx.log' where text like '%OUT:%' OR text like '%IN:%' OR text like '%TIMESTAMP%' OR text like '%DENIED%'" -o:datagrid
```

Output of the query is :

```
DATE           TIME
NULL           03:09:49
NULL           03:09:49
NULL           03:10:44
NULL           03:11:52
2015-02-06     03:12:40
NULL           03:13:37
NULL           03:18:22
NULL           03:21:18
NULL           03:21:32
NULL           03:24:19
NULL           03:26:02
```

When i want this data to flow into SQL table I get the following error:

QUERY :

```
logparser -i:Textline "select TO_DATE(TO_TIMESTAMP(TRIM(EXTRACT_SUFFIX(text,0,'TIMESTAMP')),'M/d/yyyy'))AS DATE, TO_TIME(TO_TIMESTAMP(TRIM(EXTRACT_TOKEN(text,0,'(')),'H:mm:ss')) as TIME INTO Ptclog from 'C:\ptclmgrd.log' where text like '%OUT:%' OR text like '%IN:%' OR text like '%TIMESTAMP%' OR text like '%DENIED%'" -o:SQL -server:KANNA\SQLEXPRESS -database:Flex -driver:"SQL Server Native Client 11.0" -username:sa -password:XXXXXX
```

ERROR:

Task aborted.
SQL table column "Time" data type is not compatible with SELECT clause item
  "TIME" (type TIMESTAMP)

The data type selected in SQLEXPRESS is

> time(0).

The data flows to the column if i select the datatype as :

> "datetime"

But this adds a default date in front of time which is nuisance. e.g the time is shown as :

```
DATE        TIME
2015-02-06  2015-01-01 03:12:40.000
NULL        2015-01-01 07:55:49.000
NULL        2015-01-01 06:46:50.000
NULL        2015-01-01 06:55:40.000
NULL        2015-01-01 01:57:25.000
NULL        2015-01-01 02:36:41.000
```

Is there a way the time can be represented in hh:mm:ss format in sql express 2014 DB ?

Following are sample entries in the log file that is being queried:

```
3:12:40 (lmgrd) TIMESTAMP 2/6/2015
3:13:37 (ptc_d) OUT: "PROE_Flex3CG" e1cx@D43F2STC  
3:18:22 (ptc_d) OUT: "PROE_Flex3C" u234566@D5712Sf8  
3:21:18 (ptc_d) OUT: "PROE_Flex3C" u234566@D5712Sf8  
3:21:32 (ptc_d) OUT: "PROE_Flex3C" U524863@D9NR972S  
3:24:19 (ptc_d) IN: "PROE_Flex3CG" e1cx@D43F2STC  
3:26:02 (ptc_d) OUT: "PROE_Flex3C" m0ax@2SD3TC3F  
3:26:46 (ptc_d) OUT: "PROE_Flex3C" 06u1015@03tjn-proe  
3:26:48 (ptc_d) OUT: "26" 06u1015@03tjn-proe  
3:26:48 (ptc_d) OUT: "10114" 06u1015@03tjn-proe  
4:34:39 (ptc_d) DENIED: "26" 74U1027@MZBOXSGH61108  (Licensed number of users already reached. (-4,342:10054 ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no, LogParser does not support a time-of-day type. You may try to send your DATE and TIME columns together as a single Datetime, or send the TIME column as a string and hope SQL server will convert it to a Time...

Comment: Thanks Gabriele.  I had thought To_TIME would do the trick. Its really challenging to append Date Field in front of the pure time-stamp. In this case Date comes in some weird format that too at an interval of 6 hours. But then “A challenge only becomes an obstacle when you bow to it.” !